# I can't find the Checkout tab in woocommerce settings

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, checkout

I have created a checkout page. Whenever I click the checkout button. It redirects to checkout page which is empty. The checkout tab is missing in the woocommerce settings.

Checkout status

[image: Checkout status]

Status

[image: Status]

Comment: Share your status page is there checkout page selected

Comment: Please check the link. checkout status

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went through the snapshot that you have posted. Error was "Page does not contain the shortcode". Now, I think you have created and set the checkout page but have not used woocommerce checkout shortcode on the page.
So, paste the follwoing shortcode of woocommerce on the checkout page.

```
[woocommerce_checkout]
```

For more information about woocommerce configuration you can follow this link
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/configuring-woocommerce-settings/

Comment: hie. Same issue here, hv the shortcode in place, but still cannot find checkout tab. pls help

Answer (score 0):

In your this screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOW0C.png it clearly says that short code is missing, for that you need to put checkout short code.

```
[woocommerce_checkout]
```

Simply edit the checkout page and paste that code and it will start working.